# Remove duplicates from within two two tables and past into a new table

Tags: sql, duplicates, ms-access-2007

Can I use SQL to extract data into a new table any duplicates within two existing tables?

The table below is a snapshot taken from an ERP system Pre my visit.

```
PRE
CO          Otp Los His Whs Fac
11889204    C20 22  66  1BA 1BA
11889132    C23 22  66  1BA 1BA
11888835    C20 23  66  1BA 1BA
11887689    C20 22  66  1BA 1BA
11884977    C20 22  22  1BA 1BA
11884624    C20 22  99  1BA 1BA
```

The table below is a snapshot taken after my visit.

```
POST
CO          Otp Los His Whs Fac
11889204    C20 22  66  1BA 1BA
11889132    C23 22  66  1BA 1BA
11888835    C20 23  66  1BA 1BA
11882804    C20 22  77  1BA 1BA
11882724    C20 22  77  1BA 1BA
11882521    C20 22  77  1BA 1BA
11882431    C20 22  22  1BA 1BA
11881410    C20 22  22  1BA 1BA
11881282    C20 22  22  1BA 1BA
```

Now what I want is the POST visit table to show only new records, and SQL to remove any records which are duplicated in the PRE and POST tables and create a new table called outstanding and paste the duplicates there.

Now I am learning SQL but this is slightly out my depth. Anyone know if this is possible??

Comment: @DaymoClark: if you think there is an appropriate answer, please mark it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CO, Otp, Los, His, Whs, Fac
FROM POST
```

After that in the table POST will only one record for each CO value.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, ive tried this and it just brings up all the data from the POST table and doesn't actually bring up the duplicates between the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

As your post is tagged with Access 2007, I guess you need Access SQL:

First, create the duplicate table:

```
INSERT INTO tblOutstanding (CO, Otp, Los, His, Whs, Fac) 
SELECT tblPRE.CO, tblPRE.Otp, tblPRE.Los, tblPRE.His, tblPRE.Whs, tblPRE.Fac
FROM tblPRE INNER JOIN tblPOST ON tblPRE.CO=tblPOST.CO
```

Second, delete the duplicates:

```
DELETE * FROM tblPOST
WHERE tblPOST.CO IN (
SELECT tblPRE.CO FROM tblPRE INNER JOIN tblPOST ON tblPRE.CO=tblPOST.CO
)
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, ive pasted the following into access

INSERT INTO newtable (CO, Otp, Los, His, Whs, Fac) 
SELECT PRE.CO, PRE.Otp, PRE.Los, PRE.His, PRE.Whs, PRE.Fac
FROM PRE INNER JOIN POST ON PRE.CO=POST.CO

Im getting an error message saying the field 'co' is an unknown field name?

Comment: tblOutstanding (or "newtable" as you named it) must exist before you insert rows. If you do not want to append rows to this table (and this table should consist only of the newly inserted rows instead), then `DELETE * FROM tblOutstanding` before you run the other queries.